# MDB onMessage() various response message for an unique request

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, ejb

I am currently very inexperienced with MDB. I would like to send various messages to a JMS response queue. The problem is that onMessage() is a transactional method and that fact does not allow me to send various message with interleaved sleeps. Is there one way to against one request message send more than one response message? I have tried with context transactions. Here is my onMessage method:

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {


        synchronized (this) {
            try {

                LOG.debug("Received a message" + SystemUtils.LINE_SEPARATOR + message);
                if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                    TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                    this.logMessage(textMessage, textMessage.getJMSDestination().toString(), "request");
                    String body = textMessage.getText();
                    Document doc = XMLHelper.parseText(body);
                    int amountOfXq = Integer.parseInt((String) AIAMultipleResponseEmulatorBean.initialCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/XQY_COUNT"));

                    for (int i = 0; i <= (amountOfXq - 1); i++) {

                            this.ctx.getUserTransaction().begin();
                        this.xqueryUri = new URI((String) AIAMultipleResponseEmulatorBean.initialCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/" + i));

                        LOG.debug(XMLHelper.prettyPrintXML(doc));
                        JMSHelper helper = JMSHelper.instance(this.destinationName);
                        TextMessage response = helper.createTextMessage();
                        System.out.println("Response just after creation: " + response.getText());
                        response.setStringProperty("MESSAGE_TYPE", "EMULATOR_RESPONSE");
                        response.setStringProperty("APPLICATION_TYPE", this.getClass().getName());
                        response.setStringProperty("APPLICATION_ID", this.getClass().getName());
                        response.setIntProperty("VERSION_ID", 1);
                        response.setJMSDeliveryMode(message.getJMSDeliveryMode());
                        LOG.debug("JMSCorrelationID=" + message.getJMSCorrelationID());
                        String osmID = this.getOSMID(message);
                        System.out.println("CorrelationID completo: " + message.getJMSCorrelationID());
                        System.out.println("CorrelationID osmID: " + osmID);
                        if( i == 0) {
                            response.setJMSCorrelationID(message.getJMSCorrelationID());
                        }else{
                            response.setJMSCorrelationID("TESA-CORR-" + osmID);
                            System.out.println("CorrelationID osmID: TESA-CORR-" + osmID);
                        }
                        response.setJMSPriority(message.getJMSPriority());
                        this.transformRequestToResponse(body, response); // HERE
                        this.logMessage(response, textMessage.getJMSDestination().toString(), "response");
                        LOG.debug(response.getText());
                        helper.sendMessageNoResponse(response);
                        //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                        Thread.sleep(5000);

                        this.ctx.getUserTransaction().commit();


                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception var9) {
                LOG.error("onMessage:Exception:[" + var9.getMessage() + "]", var9);
                this.ctx.setRollbackOnly();
            }

        }

    }
```

In the ejb-jar.xml I have set up **Required** as trans-attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to get around this:

1. Set your `trans-attribute` to NOT_SUPPORTED. This will prevent the onMessage() from being run in a transaction.
2. Use a connection factory that doesn't automatically enlist its connections in the caller's transaction (i.e. avoid JCA-based connection factories).